# How do skills work?

Tags: the-gold-factory

I'm faced with a choice between two skills. How do they work? When can I use them? How long do they last? How much damage do they do? I want to know before making my choice in case one is clearly superior to the other. Are there any more skills?

[image: Choose a skill - Thunder Bolt - Invulnerability]

Comment: FYI, you can switch skills by opening a JS console and running `skill = "thunder"` or `skill = "invuln"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of these skills can be used during combat with a cooldown:

- Thunder Bolt deals a set amount of damage based on the skill level (starting at 20, +7 damage per level) with a cooldown of 20 seconds.
- Invulnerability makes you immune to all damage for a set amount of time based on the skill level (starting at 3 seconds, +3 seconds per level) with a cooldown of 30 seconds.

You can upgrade your skill after choosing it for a gold cost. Each upgrade costs `500*skillLevel*skillLevel+500` gold bars, with no ceiling on the skill level.

Comment: Is there a maximum amount that a skill can be leveled?

Comment: @Batophobia No, aside from the practical limit of cost being a factor of the square of the skill level.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know before making my choice in case one is clearly superior to the other.

**TL;DR**:  I find **Invulnerability** to be clearly superior to **Thunder**.

At the first level, **Thunder** is essentially an extra attack.  **Invulnerability** protects you for three seconds at the first level, also effectively an extra attack as it allows you to attack once with no successful response.  At the second level, **Thunder** gives 7 more damage, a third of an attack.  **Invulnerability** prevents two attacks at the second level.

Beyond that, **Invulnerability** scales automatically with the difficulty of the monster that you face.  Whether it does ten points of damage or a thousand, **Invulnerability** prevents every attack while it is running.  **Thunder** does the same damage to every monster and can easily be outstripped by your sword.  For example, my sword currently does 100 damage and I have a level 9 **Invulnerability**.  So **Thunder** is a bit less than a single attack.  **Invulnerability** now prevents about ten attacks and so allows me to make ten free attacks.

Many monsters can kill me in two hits, as they do more than half my health in damage.  So with **Thunder**, I would do one **Thunder** and two regular attacks.  With **Invulnerability** I can do skill level plus three regular attacks.  Since regular attacks are more powerful than **Thunder**, adding just one regular attack is better than **Thunder**.

I have never successfully gone through a long enough fight to use **Invulnerability** a second time.  Perhaps **Thunder**'s shorter cooldown would allow me to use it a second time.  But even so, two **Thunder** casts is less effective than two regular attacks.

It's possible that **Thunder** is a lot cheaper.  But note that **Invulnerability** is a lot more effective.  So **Thunder** would have to be something like ten times as cheap to catch up.  And that's assuming that the next group of monsters isn't even worse, doing more damage than I have health.